Spring WebClient not following redirect
I'm trying to use Spring WebClient but it looks like it's not following redirect.
This is how I initialize the code:
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()                     
                    .followRedirect(true)
            .filter(logRequest())
            .build();

I'm trying to login to another endpoint which returns 302; I thought the client would follow the redirect but instead I get a ClientResponse with statuscode of 302 and empty body.
Am I missing anything in the client configuration? The same request done with another Http Client such as OkHttp works correctly.

Please share a code snippet showing how you are making the HTTP call. Also, share the HTTP logs that you get when you enable the « wiretap » config option on the reactor client
